# Nokogiri adding on '0' elements to parsed result in view

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, nokogiri

I am parsing an XML document with Nokogiri and when used within a view, a random 0 character is appended onto the end of the call.

**XML being parsed**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?> <entityDetail> <companyName>Test ompany</companyName>......</entityDetail>
```

**Controller**

```
@output = Coffice.find_by_cn(params[:cn])

## Function to remove any resigned directors more than two years old
@output.search('director').each do |node|
  if node.css('resignationDate').text.present?
    if node.css('resignationDate').text.first(4).to_f < 2012
      node.remove
    end
  end
end

......
  def self.find_by_cn(cn)
    path = "/data/app/ws/rest/companies/entity/v2.0/" + cn
    url_request = "http://" + @@domain + path

    stringtosign = "GET" + "\n" + @@domain + "\n" + path + "\n" + @@timestamp + "\n" + @@access_key + "\n" + @@accept + "\n"

    hash  = OpenSSL::HMAC.digest('sha256', @@secret_key, stringtosign)
    hash = Base64.strict_encode64(hash)
    headers "Authorization" => @@access_key + ":" + hash   

    output = get(path)  

    doc = Nokogiri::XML(output.body, 'UTF-8')

  end
```

**View**

```
<div class="page-header">
    <h1><%= @output.css("companyName").first.text.titleize %></h1>
</div>
```

**Rendered**

```
<div class="page-header">
    <h1>Test Company</h1>
</div>


0

0
```

**Issue**

There are random zeros appearing on the end of the view. My first thought was that there are multiple  tags within the XML but I've double checked and this is the only one (and in any case the .first call should only return the first appearance).

I had thought of using CSS or Jquery to remove these tags but this seems a bit dirty...

I have also tried other calls in the view and still get the appended 0 characters.

Comment: Post your controller action that is rendering the view, and the layout file that is being used (if any).

Comment: Updated showing controller action. Layout file is default bootstrap with no modification

Comment: You only posted one line of the action (`@output = Coffice.find_by_cn(params[:cn])`). Show the whole action method.

Comment: I don't see anything there. I wouldn't suspect the problem is with Nokogiri since the output ends at the closing </h1> tag. Everything after that would come from the action or layout, which I why I wanted to see them.

Comment: Your XML sample isn't useful for testing your code because it's missing the tags you're searching for. How can we help you if you don't provide valid input?